# Hahn-Banach theorem for proving denseness and injectivity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I got this problem from a Functional Analysis book (I suppose $^*$ denotes duality):

> Let X, Y be normed vector spaces and $T:X \rightarrow Y$ a linear and continuous function. Prove that:
>
> 1. $T(X)$ is dense in $Y$ $\iff$ $T^*$ is injective
> 2. $T^*(Y^*)$ is dense in $X^*$ $\implies$ $T$ is injective

After some investigation I found a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem that *might* be useful for both points:

> $M \subset X$ is dense $\iff \forall x^* \in X^*$ and $m \in M$ $[x^*(m)=0 \implies x^*=0]$

How ever I am struggling in the clarification of these questions:

1. What is the domain and codomain of $T^*$? Does it have any relationship with $T^+$? (please see this other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339754/linear-operators-denseness-and-injectivity))
2. Is there an easier way to match the surjective definition with density? Or should I keep trying using the consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Thanks in advance for any insights you could provide me!

---

Ok, here are more details in case anyone else needs them again (thanks to Tsemo for suggesting the use of a proof by contradiction and the kernel observation, and a friend ITCR for the dimensionality fact). Suppose $T^*(f)$ is not injective, then:

$$\exists f_1,f_2 \in Y^*s.t.[T^*(f_1)=T^*(f_2) \land f_1 \neq f_2]$$
$$\exists f_1,f_2 \in Y^*s.t.[T^*(f_1)-T^*(f_2)=0 \land f_1-f_2 \neq 0]$$
By $T^*$ linearity's:
$$\exists f_1,f_2 \in Y^*s.t.[T^*(f_1-f_2)=0 \land f_1-f_2 \neq 0]$$

Calling $f=f_1-f_2$ we have:
$$\exists f \in Y^*s.t.[T^*(f)=0 \land f \neq 0]$$

Meaning that $f \in \text{Ker}(T^*)$ so $\text{Ker}(T^*)\neq \emptyset \implies 0 \lt \text{dim(Ker}(T^*))$. Because $T^*:Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ then:

$$\text{dim(}T^*) = \text{dim(Im}(T^*)) + \text{dim(Ker}(T^*))$$

But:

$$\text{dim(}T^*) \neq \text{dim(Im}(T^*))$$

So $T(X)$ is not dense, proving the double implication.

Comment: $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$, which is what $T^+$ denotes in the linked post.  The notation used here is much more common.

Comment: I got it, thanks. The $^*$ symbol applied to an operator refers to its adjoint and applied to a vector space denotes a dual. In that case $T^*(Y^*)$ makes more sense because it means that a functional is being transformed into another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question 2. You don't need to use Hahn Banach to show the first question which is equivalent to say that $T^*$ is not injective implies that $T(X)$ is not dense.

Suppose that $T^*(f)=f\circ T=0, f\neq 0$, this implies $T(X)\subset Ker f$ which is a closed hyperplan of $Y$, so the adherence of $T(X)\subset Ker f$.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your quick response, much appreciated! Excuse me, how did you know that $T^*(f)=f \circ T = 0$? I understand that $f$ is a functional which maps vectors to scalars. Does $f≠0$ mean that $f$ is evaluated first with an element of $X$ or $Y$?